# Dask-kubernetes ConnectionError: kubectl port forward failed

Tags: python, kubernetes, dask, azure-aks

I'm running Dask Kubernetes on AKS. I'm trying to run the [example](https://kubernetes.dask.org/en/latest/kubecluster.html) given in the oficial documentation. The pod is created without problem in the cluster with the code

```
from dask_kubernetes import KubeCluster

# I'm using the default config
cluster = KubeCluster("worker-spec.yml")
```

with

```
# worker-spec.yml

kind: Pod
metadata:
  labels:
    foo: bar
spec:
  restartPolicy: Never
  containers:
  - image: daskdev/dask:latest
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    args: [dask-worker, --nthreads, '2', --no-dashboard, --memory-limit, 6GB, --death-timeout, '60']
    name: dask
    env:
      - name: EXTRA_PIP_PACKAGES
        value: git+https://github.com/dask/distributed
    resources:
      limits:
        cpu: "2"
        memory: 6G
      requests:
        cpu: "2"
        memory: 6G
```

But When I want to submit some function to do calculations

```
from dask.distributed import Client

client = Client(cluster)

client.submit(MyFunction, MyArg)
```

I get

```
ConnectionError: kubectl port forward failed
2022-02-03T16:52:30.694653Z [error    ] Unclosed client session
client_session: <aiohttp.client.ClientSession object at 0x0000027153A80448> [asyncio]
2022-02-03T16:52:30.696619Z [error    ] Unclosed client session
client_session: <aiohttp.client.ClientSession object at 0x0000027153A80AC8> [asyncio]
```

I tried to forward my pod with `kubectl port-forward` command and I couldn't. Looking related post I added into the yaml the instruction

```
    ports:
    - containerPort: 8786 #Default port for Dask scheduler
```

but nothing happened.

Comment: As you described, your pod with a worker is started. And what about the service? Is it also created and listen to 8786 port? You tried to make port-forwarding, but unsuccessful. Why? Did you get error message?

Comment: Probably unrelated, but wondering: why do you install main-branch distributed?

Comment: Did you solve the issue? I am having the same problem.

Comment: I edited networking.py to output the log from the kubectl port-forward command and it's running successfully
```default
Creating scheduler pod on cluster. This may take some time.
Forwarding from 127.0.0.1:56639 -> 8786
Forwarding from [::1]:56639 -> 8786
2022-08-18 11:52:28,871 - distributed.deploy.spec - WARNING - Cluster closed without starting up
```
See related issue in the library https://github.com/dask/dask-kubernetes/issues/533